Display pattern in Adobe Livecycle for a field not showing in SAP C4C
I've created a Display Pattern a num{z,zzz,zz9.99} for a field, entering also the local settings.
When I'm trying to preview the PDF on the Adobe Livecyle and entering the value for the field is working properly (Example: I'm entering 5000000 and automatically is converted to 5,000,000.000).
The problem is when I save the template (XDP file) in SAP C4C under Opportunities (Spanish), and trying to preview the summary of one opportunity where the field is set up as 3.000.000,23 COP, it showed on the PDF AS 3000000.23 COP without any specified formatting


